# Create a list of review queue for sites I have the privilege on SE.com

Tags: feature-request, review

I can't remember what sites I have review privileges on, because I am a member of beta and non beta and I'm forgetful.

Please can a page be added to the Stack Exchange homepage that has all the sites I can fully review on? And maybe a link to the review page for them.

By fully review I mean the 3k (on graduated sites) / 1k (on public betas) / 500 (on private betas) rep level.

Comment: There are different types of reviews requiring different rep levels. Do you want a specific one, or all? Also, the network profile pretty much covers this for all review levels, as you can see your rep level on all sites and just cross reference the privileges page or review page to see required rep.

Comment: @James yes, that would be fine (i.e. all that are 3k +) but then you have beta ones halfway down the list.

Comment: Do you (or, most people) not go to a site for reasons, and then review as a secondary reason for being there? Or, would actually you look at a list of sites you can review specifically to find somewhere you can review? If the latter, which is great for the sites, then perhaps if other users were to use this and get some reviewing done, it would be better to show on the list reviews pending for each site (not individual review totals, just a sum total of any/all for that site). I doubt that would happen, but it would get reviews moving along if everyone used it.

Comment: @James both. Sometimes I will sit down for an hour and just review the maximum on all sites I can.

Comment: @nicael yep, you're right :)